# How to get Quartz jobs running in a multi-ApplicationContext environment?

Tags: java, spring, osgi, quartz-scheduler, applicationcontext

I have a Spring Web application with an `applicationContext.xml` loaded through a `ContextLoaderListener` in an `XmlWebApplicationContext`. The application context has a Quartz scheduler (defined with a `SchedulerFactoryBean` like [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz-cron)) but has no trigger nor job details.

During loading of this main application context, I load some "plug-in" JARs containing their own `pluginApplicationContext.xml` file.
Each `pluginApplicationContext.xml` is loaded in a `GenericXmlApplicationContext` as a child of the main `XmlWebApplicationContext`.

Those plug-ins may contain Quartz jobs (`QuartzJobBean`) which are scheduled within the scheduler discussed above. Scheduling have to be done programmatically through the Quartz API but this is fine for me. When the job is triggered, it is well instanciated by Quartz and, because it extends the `QuartzJobBean`, I'm able to get the current `ApplicationContext` through `setApplicationContext`.
The problem here is that I get the `XmlWebApplicationContext` instead of the `GenericXmlApplicationContext` from which the job have been scheduled. Thus, I cannot call `getBean` to retrieve the beans defined within the plugin.

I well understand why all of this happen. But I cannot find a clean and reusable solution to handle it. I've already had a look at OSGi but we're implementing this plug-in system on an existing application, not creating a new one from scratch and migrating the whole application to OSGi would be too much work to do. Do you know how OSGi and other plug-in frameworks deal with this kind of situation?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It is not clear for me. I understand that you have a plugin with its onw pluginApplicationContext.xml and the beans defined in the plugin are not accesible from main context. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I get all those spring problems but I've done these things with OSGi.

What people often do not realize is that you can embed OSGi in your existing application without making any changes to the existing code. Richard Hall describes it here http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html (the API is 100% standardized).

Having a framework, you can then run your plugins in the framework. You will have to make sure the framework exports all the application packages (see the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra launch property). Plugins and application can then communicate through services.

I've never used Quartz but I've some experience with scheduling. I register a Runnable service with cron like properties:

```
   @Component(properties="cron=1 * * * *")
   public void SomeImpl implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
        ...
     }
   }
```

You will then need to make a bundle that calls that service according to its cron specification).

Comment: Thanks Peter for this **very** interesting article! Indeed, it will not solve my problem right now but it helps a lot understanding issues around plugin systems embedded in existing application.

Answer (score 0):

I agree [osgi](/questions/tagged/osgi) is a good approach, but maybe you can simply crate one huge application context (to rule them all)? Instead of manually starting new child application context based on `pluginApplicationContext.xml` file simply add:

```
<import resource="classpath:/pluginApplicationContext.xml"/>
```

And this will find all plugins and merge their beans into a single application context. From architecture point of view this is a worse approach, but it will work if you discover all plugins at startup time.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for your answer. Could this approach work if the `pluginApplicationContext.xml` files are located in JAR loaded at application startup (before Spring... how?) in other `ClassLoader`s? The JAR plugins are not in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and we want to keep them outside the Webapp ARchive because the plugins are customer specific, the Webapp is not.

Comment: @FlorentPaillard: it will work if your customers' JARs/classes are visible from the `ClassLoader` that starts Spring. It is easy to try.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Spring is loaded automatically by the servlet container within the `WebappClassLoader`. As my customers classes/JARs are located outside server/webapp standard directories they must be loaded "programmatically", at startup, through `ClassLoader`s which are children of the `WebappClassLoader` so they're not visible from it. Am I missing something?